# Login-Links in Salesforce: sometimes they work - sometimes they don't

Tags: urlhacking, url, automation, login

As consultants and developers we login to a very huge number of different development- and client-orgs. We use the environment hub, but beside the hub it comes very handy to use login links in the form of:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/?un=username@example.com
```

It could be also extended (however I would not recommend it) to this form:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/?un=username@example.com&pw=YourPassword
```

In the first notation, you usually get into a login-screen with a prepopulated username - which is very nice and exactly what I like. The second form would process the login and depending on how you save you bookmarks it's very risky.

Now using the first notation my experience is, that the prepopulation only works "sometimes". I'm using Firefox and was not able to reproduce exactly when and why it works or fails. If it fails, the login UI comes up empty - if it works, the username is filled already - using the exactly same URL. The behavior feels random and did not change over Firefox's version evolution (tested on FF20 up to FF35 now). Right now I tried it in Chrome and it worked fine - but I have no long-term experience with that in Chrome.

Does anyone know why this mechanism could randomly fail sometimes or what is needed to ensure that it works always? Could it conflict with the "Saved user names / Remember User Name"?

And I don't know, if this is an officially supported functionality or if it could be a form of URL hacking. This would also be good to clarify.