# What do you use to speed up login process for salesforce development?

Tags: tools

What do you use to speed up the login process for salesforce development.
I am sure you have quite number of env to handle when you are working with salesforce. I use chrome browser plugin called "Force.com LOGINS" to remember the login info for different env or alfred+ipassword5 so I can just type in the name of env in the alfred and open up the browser to login to a specific env. Do you use any plugin allow login to different environment in the same browser but different tab?( I saw this plugin called "MultiLogin" does something similar but if you know a good one let me kno)

Answer (score 1):

That plugin is kind of lousy, actually. I use it for managing logins for now, but it doesn't sync across browsers, and is dependent on passwords. A better plugin would use OAuth2 instead, to keep a refresh token for easier signins. I'm working on such a plugin for Chrome, at least, but it'll be awhile before it goes public. Anyways, for now, I use the Force.com IDE. Just right-click on an active IDE project, and choose Force.com > Show in Salesforce Web, and you're immediately logged in. This is by far easier than managing the plugin, since I write most of my code in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I use the environment hub, which comes with SSO and some Org management features. Now if you spin DEs there they get automatically connected and you can manually add other orgs : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=environment_hub_main.htm

Besides the hub it comes very handy to use login links in the form of:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/?un=username@example.com
```

It could be also extended (however for security reasons,  I would not recommend it) to this form:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/?un=username@example.com&pw=YourPassword
```

Unfortunately it's not working sometimes (rarely) [Login-Links in Salesforce: sometimes they work - sometimes they don't](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63717/login-links-in-salesforce-sometimes-they-work-sometimes-they-dont)

Firefox sync is keeping me this up to date for about 10 portable Firefoxes so I can be logged into many orgs at the same time. I replaced the portable FF app-icons, so that I can easily distinguish between the parallel logins by window and app-icon - on Windows7 at least.

I like @sfdcfox's approach with Force.com IDE, but possibly the credentials there are either light or not encrypted. We could check this out since it's open source.

Comment: Passwords in the IDE are encrypted, as far as I can tell. But my hard drive is mostly encrypted anyways, so it's still protected by my computer's password.

Comment: The environment hub is awesome anyways, I just haven't set it up since it's not part of the scope of what we're working on, but I'll have to remember to try it out on my next project.

Comment: @sfdcfox -  as always there are light and shadows but for org spinning best way I found. I think the hub is Salesforce's official answer to the Org-dshungle challenge. Easy to end up with 100+ orgs as developer.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Force.com IDE: as we don't have to enter a master password on IDE start, I suspect only a very lightweight protection. HD encryption fills the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Password1 is the only manager I trust and use. It syncs between machines, works with Chrome, Firefox & Safari. It works with the iPhone app too which is really useful if you need to quickly view something.

I think IE and windows, but I don't use them myself.

Answer (score 0):

SSO via SAML + identity provider that supports Windows authentication (Kerberos). I login to my desktop, then click on a bookmark to the org and I am in.